# File Not linking

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript file is not linking to my HTML document. When I copy the code directly into the HTML body, it works, but it doesn't work when I try to link the script file. Below is the code for both the HTML and JavaScript files:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cards-container">
    <div class="card">A<div id="aceH">&#x2665;</div></div>
    <div class="card">K<div id=kingS>&#x2660;</div></div>
    <div class="card">Q<div id="queenC">&#x2663;</div></div>
    <div class="card">J<div id="jackH">&#x2665;</div></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="shuffleCards()">Shuffle Cards</button>
  <button onclick="resetCards()">Reset Cards</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var initialOrder = [];
var cardsContainer = document.getElementById('cards-container');

// Store the initial order of the cards
var cards = Array.from(cardsContainer.getElementsByClassName('card'));
cards.forEach(function (card) {
  initialOrder.push(card);
});

function shuffleCards() {
  cards = Array.from(cardsContainer.getElementsByClassName('card'));
  cards.forEach(function (card) {
    var randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    cardsContainer.appendChild(card);
    cardsContainer.insertBefore(card, cards[randomPos]);
  });
}

function resetCards() {
  cards = Array.from(cardsContainer.getElementsByClassName('card'));
  cards.forEach(function (card, index) {
    cardsContainer.appendChild(card);
    cardsContainer.insertBefore(card, initialOrder[index]);
  });
}
```

I am new to this, so maybe it is a simple mistake. However, the JavaScript code works fine when it is directly in the HTML body.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is loading before your HTML, but it's failing because it's instantly trying to interact with the DOM. Wrap all your JS in a listener to wait for all the markup to load, or move your script tag to just before the closing `body` tag. Jatin's answer includes an example of the latter. Here's how you would do the former in plain JS (the changes are commented):

```js
// add the event listener wrapping the rest of your code
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var initialOrder = [];
  var cardsContainer = document.getElementById('cards-container');

  var cards = Array.from(cardsContainer.getElementsByClassName('card'));
  cards.forEach(function (card) {
    initialOrder.push(card);
  });

  function shuffleCards() {
    cards = Array.from(cardsContainer.getElementsByClassName('card'));
    cards.forEach(function (card) {
      var randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
      cardsContainer.appendChild(card);
      cardsContainer.insertBefore(card, cards[randomPos]);
    });
  }

  function resetCards() {
    cards = Array.from(cardsContainer.getElementsByClassName('card'));
    cards.forEach(function (card, index) {
      cardsContainer.appendChild(card);
      cardsContainer.insertBefore(card, initialOrder[index]);
    });
  }

  // put the above functions on window so you can
  // access them in your html
  window.shuffleCards = shuffleCards;
  window.resetCards = resetCards;
});
```

Also see the comment below this answer; you could use the `defer` attribute and keep your script tag in the head, as in `<script defer src="script.js></script>`

Comment: Or Just add **defer** to the script tag to load it after the dom is loaded. Sometimes, I want all my included files at one place for better readability/debugging.

Comment: @AniketPandey oh definitely. For some reason I always forget about `defer`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the JS isn't at fault, you're very close. The HTML file just needs a little more understanding of how to access the `script.js` file.

Assuming your file structure looks something like:

```
project folder
  index.html
  script.js
  maybeSomeStyles.css
```

As a result, you'll want to let the HTML file know that `script.js` is within the same directory by adding a relative path identifier (you'll see a lot more of this as you use JS more).

Try replacing your script line with the following:
`<script src="./script.js"></script>`

`.` means *this* directory, while `..` means the *parent* directory.

Comment: I just tried that and it isnt working either. I am going to try and restart my system I just noticed VS code has an update for me maybe that is it. I just opened a few other files that I have with js linked in the HTML and they opened fine so Im kinda lost, I can post the entire code and someone can try it on their system to see if it works. it is just simple code. A few playing cards just getting started on a new project and already have a headache. thanks for your help

Comment: I forgot about this! I hope you've seen the other comments, it seems likely that the JS was loading before any markup.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in the body as sometimes it takes time to render the script if it is placed in head :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cards-container">
    <div class="card">A<div id="aceH">&#x2665;</div></div>
    <div class="card">K<div id=kingS>&#x2660;</div></div>
    <div class="card">Q<div id="queenC">&#x2663;</div></div>
    <div class="card">J<div id="jackH">&#x2665;</div></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="shuffleCards()">Shuffle Cards</button>
  <button onclick="resetCards()">Reset Cards</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your java script code is fine don't worry about that .